# Amilo Pa 2548 graphics chip, code 43

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, vga, integrated-graphics

driver of dedicated GPU nVidia GeForce 8400M G, says error code 43. Graphics in Vista vent VGA (4-bit colors, 640x480 resolution). Vista won't allow any change to higer resolution.

Already tried up/down-grade GPU drivers.
Already tried reinstall operating system.

Live CD of Ubuntu wont boot. 
Live CD of [Linux slax](http://www.slax.org/) boots just fine, with good colors and slightly better resolution.

Why Ubuntu won't boot, and slax do? Is there any hope, that the chip is not dead? 
Is there any way to live with dead GPU? Can we dedicate processors second core to emulate graphics? We don't wont to trash this notebook.

===
Notebook: Fujistu Siemens Amilo Pa 2548